# Perl regular expression unintendedly seems to be modifying a source String

Tags: regex, perl

Am trying to match some data patterns from a file in a Perl program. Since the match could be over multiple lines, I have made the line seperator as undefined.

```
$/ = undef ;
```

Now, since the match can be across multiple lines and more than one, I am using smgi modifiers.

```
if ( $msgText =~ /$msgTypeExpr/smgi )
```

Now, the problem I am having is that the variable $msgText above gets modified though I am not replacing it.

Here is the relevant code:

```
open (HANDLE1,"$file") || die "cannot open file \n";
$/ = undef ;
while ( my $msgText = <HANDLE1> )
{
        my $msgTypeExpr = "<city\\W+";

        print "Attempt 1:\n";
        if ( $msgText =~ /$msgTypeExpr/smgi )
        {
                print "matched\n";
        }
        else
        {
                print " not matched \n";
        }

        print "Attempt 2:\n";
        if ( $msgText =~ /$msgTypeExpr/smgi )
        {
                print "matched\n";
        }
        else
        {
                print " not matched \n";
        }
}
```

The test input file looks like this:

```
<city
 name="abc">
</city>
```

One would expect the pattern to match twice but it is matching the first time only and not the second time around.

I have temporarily fixed this issue with assigning to a temp variable for now before matching and using that temp variable to match.

```
my $tmpMsgText = $msgText ;
```

This is the first time I am posting a question on this forum, so please pardon any etiquettes mistakes I may have made and also please be kind enough to point them out so that I don't repeat in the future.

Comment: If the file is an XML file you should be parsing it with an XML parser and not try to do it with regex.

Comment: raina77ow - He is executing the same thing 2x, so I believe he wanted to match <city both of the times. But because of the /g switch, it is not happening in his code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (//g)` makes no sense. "If it matches and keeps on matching until there's no match"? Get rid of the `g`.

I don't know why you're using `s` or `m` either.

The `s` is useless since the pattern doesn't contain `.`.

The `m` is useless since the pattern doesn't contain `^` or `$`.

---

In reality, `//g` in scalar context acts as an iterator.

```
$ perl -E'$_ = "abc"; /(.)/g && say $1; /(.)/g && say $1;'
a
b
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all, I'm not sure about reading a file like that. Modifying those Perl-special variables, like $/ should be done with local, like this:

```
local $/ = undef;
```

this way the variable is only modified in the current scope (thus eliminating possible action-in-the-distance bugs). By setting $/ to undef you will read the entire file in one go, so there is no point putting a while loop there. I'd read the whole file like this:

```
open my $fh, "<", "somefile" or die;
my $content = do { local $/ = undef; <$fh> };
```

the do block restricts the modified $/ value only to that one statement (it creates a new scope).

About regex matching: remove the /g modifier after the regex. If I remember correctly, it will remember the last regex search position and continue from there. Also for detecting if a string was altered or not, print the variable before and after those matches. You will see, that they are not modified.
Instead of:

```
if ( $msgText =~ /$msgTypeExpr/smgi )
```

put:

```
if ( $msgText =~ /$msgTypeExpr/smi )
```

Comment: Yes, you remember it correctly: in scalar context, successive invocations against a string will have `//g` jump from match to match.